# How to calculate Rankits with Python?

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution

How can I calculate Rankits with Python?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankit

In particular I want to reproduce the example on Wikipedia:
So I search for a function which takes a list `[16, 22, 40, 43, 65, 75]` and then returns the corresponding rankits: `[−1.2672,   −0.6418,   −0.2016,   0.2016,   0.6418,   1.2672]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
observation = [16, 22, 40, 43, 65, 75]
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
def Q_Q_Prob(data):
    n = len(data)
    prob_level = []
    
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        prob_level.append(np.round((i-0.5)/n,5))
    Standard_normal_quantiles = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(prob_level)
    return Standard_normal_quantiles

print(Q_Q_Prob(observation))
```

This gives exact result for the example in book name : Applied Multivariate
Statistical Analysis (RICHARD A. JOHNSON)[image: see the example], However not giving exact values for the mentioned example. Sharing this because this might give you a idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that answer. However, the values i get from there are to far off: [-1.38301587 -0.67448975 -0.21041985  0.21041985  0.67448975  1.38301587]. How can I get it more accurate?

Comment: After lot of research i came to conclusion that formula used in answered code is correct. Some reference [1](https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1004&context=coe_tbf) [2](https://influentialpoints.com/notes/n3rnorm.htm)  [3](https://www.cedu.niu.edu/~walker/statistics/Lab%201E.htm) . and i think your question came from [here](https://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/thinkstats.pdf) page number 45, 4.4 Normal probability plot - Exercise 4.9. Q_Q Plot itself called rankit and used for normality check.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed Rakesh V's answer using R, which came up with your exact numbers tam tam. Not sure why the results in the book are different:

```
x<-c(16,22,40,43,65,75)
qnorm((rank(x)-0.5)/length(x))
[1] -1.3829941 -0.6744898 -0.2104284  0.2104284  0.6744898  1.3829941
```